# Check if subscription is expired with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating a web app that will have some subscriptions.  The backend is a postgres database with a user id and a date/time when their subscription expires.

```
Subscription Table
UserId SubscriptionExpiry
1      10/10/2020
```

I can write code that checks if subscription is expired and update the date/time as needed. Is there some built in postgres way to do this?

Comment: To what value should an expired subscription be updated? What is the data type of `SubscriptionExpiry`?

Comment: I think an empty date or a expired date in SubscriptionExpiry means the user has a expired subscription.

Comment: Ok - then why update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing a postgre function that takes argument UserId and you can do all the logic (updating SubscriptionExpiry for example) you need in there.

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_expired(attr type)
 RETURNS type AS
BEGIN
 -- logic
END;
LANGUAGE language_name;
```

You can call the function from the language you are using for web app simple as

```
SELECT check_expired(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux you can use a simple cron-based job scheduler for PostgreSQL (9.5 or higher): [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron).

It runs inside the database as an extension and uses the same syntax as regular cron, but it allows you to schedule PostgreSQL commands directly from the database:

```
-- Delete old data on Saturday at 3:30am (GMT)
SELECT cron.schedule('30 3 * * 6', $$DELETE FROM events WHERE event_time < now() - interval '1 week'$$);

 schedule
----------
    42
```